# How to obtain a specific path in flutter by opening that folder in windows?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I want to to print a specific path that I want to open for this I m using path provider its show me path but this path I cant choose by my choice.